# Firebase pagination in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a image posting app in which I want to fetch first five records and then when the user scrolls down to bottom next 5 records should be fetched automatically . I am ordering by "negative_time stamp" so that the latest post comes at the top . After fetching first 5 records from bottom i want the next five records . Please help . Thanks in Advance;

I am using this query for fetching next five records

```
ref_to_all_posts.orderByChild("negative_timestamp").startAt( neg_timeStamp).limitToFirst(5)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md ?

Comment: yes , but i want the data in chunks , like i have retrieved first 10 in first iteration now in 2nd i want from 11-20.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to store the `timestamp` **and** the key of the last item of the page. Then you can get the next page with:

```
ref_to_all_posts
  .orderByChild("negative_timestamp")
  .startAt(lastTimeStamp, lastKey)
  .limitToFirst(6)
```

Two things to note here:

- I pass in the `timestamp` and the key of the last item on the previous page. The Firebase Database uses these to find the item as the starting point for this query.
- We request 6 items, since the query will also return the same item. There is no way to prevent returning this overlapping item, so you have to filter it out client-side.